# rtDownload in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using rtDownload DSL block of the Jenkins JFrog Artifactory plugin in my Jenkins pipeline to download some artifacts from Artifactory.

Is there anyway I can throw an error, if the files to download are not found in Artifactory?
Jenkins justs outputs:

```
Downloading artifacts using pattern: libs-release-local/*.ear
Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
Finished resolving Build Info published dependencies.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#rtdownload-download-artifacts documentation. You will need to set `failNoOp` parameter to `true`.

Comment: Thank you, missed that information, now it works!